# Java: Graphic framework for standalone application

Tags: java, swing

My question is very simple:

What graphic framework can I use to develop a standalone application in Java ?

Usually I develop web application and I use JSF or GWT.

For standalone application, I used Swing a long time ago but is it always in development ?

Thank for your suggestion.

Comment: Swing is still in development - [JavaFX 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm) seems to be the future.

Comment: @assylias JavaFX8 with Java8

Comment: @mKorbel I did not mention it since the developer preview is not even out yet! But yes, looking forward to it!

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood JavaFX. I thought it's a language like Flex mainly used for rich web app.

Comment: @Kiva Java FX 1.xx and Java FX 2.xx have almost nothing in common. The latter is a pure java library, like Swing, that you can use to build desktop applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three major options: Swing, SWT, JavaFX.

**Swing** is very mature, well known, and although Oracle seems to push JavaFX at the moment, there is active third-party development happening, for example the SwingX open-source project had a new release last week.

**SWT** is also quite mature, and there are also new releases (last one on 14 September 2012). However, SWT never got as popular as Swing.

**JavaFX** is relatively new, therefore not as mature as the other two (version 2 is a complete rewrite, they even changed the programming language between the versions 1 and 2) and so far there seems to have no big adoption, but Oracle still didn't give up, so anything can happen in the future...

Note that for SWT and JavaFX you have to bundle the runtime with your app (If your users have Java7u6, JavaFX 2.2 is bundled, but by default jfxrt.jar is not in the classpath). Also note that you can extend a Swing app with JavaFX components, but not the other way around.

Comment: I would not call JavaFX immature any more. Version 2.0 was released 18 months ago and a lot of progress has been made since. It certainly doesn't have the stability and ecosystem of Swing yet but you can build a reliable application with JavaFX right now. And the release cycle is quite fast.

Comment: @assylias: I guess a good developer was able to build reliable applications already with JavaFX 1, and it still disappeared... However, I will edit the wording of my answer :)

Comment: Minor correction to Ibalazscs answer - for JavaFX development, you don't have to bundle the runtime with your application - the JavaFX runtime is included in the Oracle Java and OpenJDK runtimes since the Java 7u6 release.